# fancyhdr (or alternative?) on first page only in documentclass letter

Tags: margins, fancyhdr, letters

Similar questions have been asked before but none of them seem to answer my question. I want a `\documentclass{letter}` with an image in the header of the first page only. I can achieve this with `fancyhdr`, but this causes the top margin to be huge on all subsequent pages. How can I get `fancyhdr` to affect only the first page? Or, if there's another way to do it without `fancyhdr`, that would be fine too.

MWE below. I tried to define a "plain" style to apply to subsequent pages, but that has no effect unless I uncomment the `\thispagestyle{plain}`, which fixes the margin on the second page but removes the image from the first page!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter}
\usepackage[margin=1.3in]{geometry}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancypagestyle{empty}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[L]{\vspace{65pt}\includegraphics[height=1in, keepaspectratio=true]{example-image}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\pagestyle{plain}

\address{\hfill 123 Fake St \\ \hfill Faketown \\ \hfill Fakelandia 54321}

\date{} 
\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{321 Ekaf St \\ Nwotekaf \\ Aidnalekaf 12345}
\opening{Dear You Guys:}

%\thispagestyle{plain}

\lipsum[1-6]

\closing{Yours sincerely,\\
\fromsig{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image}} \\
\fromname{John Hancock}
}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use package `scrlayer`. It redefines `empty` as layer page style. So you can declare a new layer and add this to page style `empty`:

```
\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  textarea,
  contents={\includegraphics[height=1in, keepaspectratio=true]{kitty}}
]{letterimage}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{empty}{letterimage}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter}
\usepackage[margin=1.3in]{geometry}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage
  [demo]% only for the example because I do not have the pictures
  {graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  textarea,
  contents={\includegraphics[height=1in, keepaspectratio=true]{kitty}}
]{letterimage}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{empty}{letterimage}

\address{\hfill 123 Fake St \\ \hfill Faketown \\ \hfill Fakelandia 54321}
\date{} 
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{321 Ekaf St \\ Nwotekaf \\ Aidnalekaf 12345}
\opening{Dear You Guys:}
\lipsum[1-6]
\closing{Yours sincerely,\\
\fromsig{\includegraphics[scale=.2]{signature}} \\
\fromname{John Hancock}
}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

---

If there are other pages using page style `empty` too, you can define a new page style for the first page of the letter:

```
\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  textarea,
  contents={\includegraphics[height=1in, keepaspectratio=true]{kitty}}
]{letterimage}
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{letterfirstpage}{letterimage}
```

Then you can patch `\opening` to replace `\thispagestyle{empty}`:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\opening
  {\thispagestyle{empty}}{\thispagestyle{letterfirstpage}}
  {}{\PatchFailed}
```

Now it is possible to use page style `empty` for the other pages:

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter}
\usepackage[margin=1.3in]{geometry}
%\pagenumbering{gobble}% <- removed
\usepackage
  [demo]% only for the example because I do not have the pictures
  {graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  textarea,
  contents={\includegraphics[height=1in, keepaspectratio=true]{kitty}}
]{letterimage}
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{letterfirstpage}{letterimage}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\opening
  {\thispagestyle{empty}}{\thispagestyle{letterfirstpage}}
  {}{\PatchFailed}

\pagestyle{empty}% empty page style for the other pages

\address{\hfill 123 Fake St \\ \hfill Faketown \\ \hfill Fakelandia 54321}
\date{} 
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{321 Ekaf St \\ Nwotekaf \\ Aidnalekaf 12345}
\opening{Dear You Guys:}
\lipsum[1-6]
\closing{Yours sincerely,\\
\fromsig{\includegraphics[scale=.2]{signature}} \\
\fromname{John Hancock}
}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

Answer (score 4):

A simple `\raisebox` with optional `[0pt][0pt]` to fool LaTeX will do:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter}
\usepackage[margin=1.3in]{geometry}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancypagestyle{empty}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[L]{\raisebox{-\dimexpr 50pt+1in}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[height=1in, keepaspectratio=true]{example-imagea}}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\pagestyle{plain}

\address{\hfill 123 Fake St \\ \hfill Faketown \\ \hfill Fakelandia 54321}

\date{}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{letter}{321 Ekaf St \\ Nwotekaf \\ Aidnalekaf 12345}
\opening{Dear You Guys:}

\pagestyle{plain}

\lipsum[1-6]

\closing{Yours sincerely,\\
\fromsig{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{signature}} \\
\fromname{John Hancock}
}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could use a highly configurable letter class like `scrlttr2`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fromalign=right,fromlogo,backaddress=false]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[margin=1.3in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setkomavar{fromname}{John Hancock}
\setkomavar{fromlogo}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{123 Fake St \\ Faketown \\ Fakelandia 54321}
\setkomavar{date}{}
\setkomavar{signature}{\includegraphics[height=2\baselineskip,width=4cm]{example-image}\\
 \usekomavar{fromname}
}
\let\raggedsignature\raggedright
\makeatletter
\@setplength{firstheadwidth}{\textwidth}
\@setplength{firstheadvpos}{\dimexpr\topmargin+1in\relax}
\@addtoplength{toaddrvpos}{-2cm}
\@setplength{toaddrhpos}{\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in\relax}
\@addtoplength{refvpos}{-4cm}
\@setplength{sigbeforevskip}{0pt}
\@setplength{sigindent}{.5\textwidth}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{321 Ekaf St \\ Nwotekaf \\ Aidnalekaf 12345}
\opening{Dear You Guys:}

\lipsum[1-6]

\closing{Yours sincerely}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of `scrlttr2` you can also use a standard class or a KOMA-Script class and package `scrletter`. The package provides almost the same functionality like the class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simpler option. In the first page, set `\thispagestyle{fancy}`, with the changes in the header that you want. Then, at the beginning of the second page, reset `\pagestyle{fancy}` with the settings for the header without the figure and the usual settings for the remaining pages. That is, include `\pagestyle{fancy}` together with `\rhead{}`, `\rfoot{\thepage}` etc.

Comment: This won't prevent `fancyhdr` to increase `\headheight` as a result of the large head of the first page, because `\@fancyvbox` uses a `\global\setlength`.